# Show selected option after submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to show my selectedvalue from the selectbox. 
If i 'Submit' you're going to 'insert.php' if I show my answer it shows the 'ID' but I want to show the 'name' of it. But my value needs to stay 'ID'.

This is my Select.
It shows the autoname ( that's working good )

**(index.php)**

```
<select class="select-css" name="car" id="car">
    <option value="">Select car</option>
    <?php 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['carid'].'">'.$row['carname'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Car not available</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>

</select>
<select id="color" name="color" style="display: none;"> 
    <option value="">Selecteer color</option>
</select>
```

My button posts it to insert.php

```
<button style="display: none;" type="submit" id="test" name="submit" >Submit</button>
```

My insert.php looks like this:

```
$carz=$_POST['car'];
$colorz=$_POST['color'];   
var_dump($colorz);
var_dump($carz);

mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO opslag (answer,answer1) VALUES ('$carz','$colorz')"); 
echo ("So your options are $carz and $colorz");
```

When I insert the query it inserts 'the ID' because my values are my IDs. But I need to show the name instead of id

Comment: That would be a wrong move. You should always insert an id instead of a name. You could always get the name based on id using JOINS

Comment: @YourCommonSense I need to show at the end my choices. If I show the choices its automaticly showing the 'ID's' instead of names. I cant show the IDS at my website.

Comment: @YourCommonSense How can I show the 'names' instead of ID?

Comment: **That** should have been the question you asked.

Comment: I know , my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Browser will send field value based on option `value` attributes. If you want your form to submit the `carname` instead of `carid`, you should put it into the `value` attributes. Such as:

```php
<select class="select-css" name="car" id="car">
    <option value="">Select car</option>
    <?php 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['carname']).'">'.$row['carname'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Car not available</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>

</select>
<select id="color" name="color" style="display: none;"> 
    <option value="">Selecteer color</option>
</select>
```

Same apply to the color selection.

Note: Remember to escape your variables for SQL. Try [PDO prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for query so it would automatically quote and escape your input.

Comment: Why suggest PDO when OP is using `mysqli_*`? What's the benefit in switching? '*Remember to escape your variables for SQL.*' - No. *Don't* rely on escaping. Use prepared statements.

Comment: I want to but I'm getting my values from my CarID. This website is for a project. I need to show the dropdown 'car' after I select a car I need to show 'color' that's connected with my cars. I need to have 'id' at my value.

Comment: The link I provided was about prepared statement.

Comment: @KoalaYeung but what you wrote before that contradicts your link and so does '*query statement.*' to describe a prepared statement. It causes confusion. Why even suggest escaping?

Comment: I suggests PDO prepare because it would automatically quote and escape the user input. I've updated my original answer to reduce confusion.

Comment: Prepared statements don't quote/escape your values.

Comment: @Goks: I'm confused. Your question asked how you may modify the insert statement to insert car name. And yet you want CarID as input?

Comment: @KoalaYeung actually what i want is exactly after i have sent it that the choices are shown on the screen as names and not as ids

Comment: Then I think you should modify the code that shows submit results to show `carname` instead of `carid`. You can build and assoc array with `carid` as key and `carname` as value. Then you may print the `$carnames[$submitted_car_id]` on your screen instead of `$submitted_car_id`.

Comment: @Script47 For clarity: the benefit is apparent as raw PDO is more user-friendly than raw mysqli. Especially when it comes to prepared statements. I do agree, however, it's a bit off topic. Regarding escaping, by default PDO actually [quote and escape for mysql](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation), unless told otherwise.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Interesting. '*raw PDO is more user-friendly than raw mysqli.*' - Could you give me an example for future references?

Comment: @Script47 well it's easy: [PDO insert](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert#positional) vs [Mysqli insert](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert#prepare): 2:4 by the number of lines and overall complexity. [PDO select](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#prepare_positional) vs. [Mysqli select](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select#prepare): 3:6 with a lot of cryptic, non-obvious and generally useless function calls on mysqli side.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks, I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery to get the selected text of dropdown using

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

and store the above value in some variable and send this data to the backend through `ajax`.

**OR**

Set the data into the value attribute of the dropdown. The browser will send the data in value attribute to the backend.